# Notepad++ RegEx Find/Replace specified group and backreference

Tags: regex, replace, find, backreference

I´ve had some trouble getting my RegEx find/replace working in NPP for hours. Here´s some code out of the files I´m working on:
https://regex101.com/r/kQdy4L/6/
My goal is to replace all the "0>.|.|..." by their id name

**test string**

```
<movingPart index="0>8|1|3" referencePoint="0>8|1|0|4" referenceFrame="0>" scaleZ="true"/>
bla
bla
<i3dMapping id="KroneComprimaV180XC" node="0>" />
<i3dMapping id="novoGripPart2_fixPoint" node="0>8|1|0|4" />
<i3dMapping id="novoGrip_part2" node="0>8|1|3" />
```

**substitution**

```
<movingPart index="novoGrip_part2" referencePoint="novoGripPart2_fixPoint" referenceFrame="KroneComprimaV180XC" scaleZ="true"/>
bla
bla
<i3dMapping id="KroneComprimaV180XC" node="0>" />
<i3dMapping id="novoGripPart2_fixPoint" node="0>8|1|0|4" />
<i3dMapping id="novoGrip_part2" node="0>8|1|3" />
```

After some tial´n´error I got this RegEx

```
(".[>].*?")|<i3dMapping id=(?P<name>".*?") node=(".[>].*?")
(".[>].*?")|<i3dMapping id=(?P<name>".*?") node=(".[>].*?")\=1
```

Which do find either nodes+ids or only the nodes I need to replace however I can´t figure out how to replace all "0>.|.|." with the id name

Thanks for helping me out, this is the first time I get confronted with RegEx, so this is all very confusing to me.
Cheers Fred

Comment: Can you please add an example of expected input and output?

Comment: @AryJazz thanks for helping me, the RegExp code posted by Nick does exactly what I was looking for. If you are still interested in input and outup check out his regex101 [link](https://regex101.com/r/03rJET/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regexp to do the replacements for you:

```
(?<=(index|Point|Frame)=")([^"]+)(?=".*?id="([^"]+)" node="\2")
```

It uses a positive lookbehind for one of `index="`, `Point="` or `Frame="` (note we have to cut the `reference` off because a lookbehind must be of fixed length), followed by some number of non-`"` characters (that value being captured in group 2), then a positive lookahead for a string which looks like `id="someidvalue" node="\2"` where the `\2` refers to the value captured earlier. The value `someidvalue` is captured in group 3.

You can then replace with `$3`. Note that you need to use `Replace All`, for some reason Notepad++ doesn't like replacing this on a match by match basis.

Here's a demo of the regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/03rJET/5)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for. It turned out there are some more dos and don´ts i needed to consider but thanks to you explanation I was able to modify the code so I can use it for all my files (lookbehind with fixed length, never would have thought about that). 

Thanks mate,